# Java split function: Is this the expected behaviour?

Tags: java, split

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        String str1="a,,";
        String str2="a,,b";
        System.out.println(str1+" len="+str1.split(",").length);
        System.out.println(str2+" len="+str2.split(",").length);
    }
}
```

The output is

```
a,, len=1
a,,b len=3
```

Isn't the number of parts supposed to be 3 in both the cases?

Comment: Yep. Sorry for the duplication. I could not find it earlier. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, what you are seeing is completely normal. The best I can say is ciopy-paste the documentation:

> The array returned by this method contains each substring of this
>   string that is terminated by another substring that matches the given
>   expression or is terminated by the end of the string. The substrings
>   in the array are in the order in which they occur in this string. If
>   the expression does not match any part of the input then the resulting
>   array has just one element, namely this string.
>
> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is
>   applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If
>   the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at
>   most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and
>   the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched
>   delimiter. If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as
>   many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero
>   then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array
>   can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

You need to read the documentation to understand better =)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behavior according to the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

For more control, consider looking into the `String#split(String, int)` method.

Answer (score 0):

This example is there in oracle Documentation, this solves all the confusion.

String "boo:and:foo"
Regex   "o"

Result { "b", "", ":and:f" }

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
String str1="a,,";
String str2="a,,b";
System.out.println(str1+" len="+str1.split(",", -1).length);
System.out.println(str2+" len="+str2.split(",", -1).length);
```