# Split method ignores commas at end

Tags: java, string

When I split a string with multiple commas at end, they are ignored in array. Is it correct ?

```
    String a = "a,b,c,,f,,";
    String[] sdf = a.split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < sdf.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(sdf[i]);
    }
```

Or am I missing something.

Output I am getting is

```
[a,b,c, ,f]
```

I want to take those blank values into consideration, expecting something like this

```
[a,b,c, ,f, ,]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use:

```
public String[] split(String regex,
                  int limit)
```

and say:

```
String[] sdf = a.split(",", -1);
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
[a, b, c, , f, , ]
```

Quoting from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as
>   possible and the array can have any length.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's the way it's supposed to work.

See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19562965/1701776) for more details, including how to bypass that behavior.

(tl;dr: use `a.split(",", -1)` to include the empty elements.)